# Get return code of a Docker container run with --rm -d

Tags: docker

If I **docker run** a container with some script inside using --rm and --detach, how can I found the RC of that container ? I.e. whether the script inside the container finished successfully or failed ?

Because of --rm flag I can't see that container in **docker ps --all** after it finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, since you're explicitly asking Docker to clean up after the image.  That will include all of the metadata like the exit status.

On the other hand, if you're actively planning to check the status code anyways, you'll have the opportunity to do the relevant cleanup yourself.

```sh
CONTAINER_ID=$(docker run -d ...)
...
docker stop "$CONTAINER_ID" # if needed
docker wait "$CONTAINER_ID" # produces its exit status
CONTAINER_RC=$?
docker rm "$CONTAINER_ID"

if [ "$CONTAINER_RC" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "container failed" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check weather the script works is first capture the script response using `command1 > everything.txt 2>&1`

And lastly, you can go inside to the running container using `docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash`